# Simultaneously adding points and linking

Tags: php, sql

i got this simple points system, where when a user clicks on the image it adds 20 points to the database through a mysql query. It works, however, I'm trying to make it so that when a user clicks on the image that it not only adds points to a users database but also goes to a website. I added  correctly but then it links but doesn't add points. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: can you please share your code otherwise your question may get lots of downvote

Comment: Its something that you want dynamically. Either you have to refresh your whole page or go for Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Ajax` for inserting `points` in your database and after response`(in your success method)` send it to your desired URL.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/test/points.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function (dataCheck) {
           if (dataCheck) {
            window.location = 'www.example.com';
           }

        }
    });
```